# My nestjs application uses typeorm and does not release the connection

Tags: mysql, nestjs, typeorm, mysql2, nestjs-typeorm

I found that my nestjs application, after using typeorm to query mysql, the connection was idle but not released

This is the configuration of my nestjs using typeorm version 0.2.45 to connect to mysql:

```js
TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'mysql',
      host: '',
      port: '',
      timezone: '+08:00',
      username: '',
      password: '',
      database: '',
      charset: '',
      // dateStrings: true,
      autoLoadEntities: '',
      bigNumberStrings: '',
      synchronize: true, 
      supportBigNumbers: true,
      logging: ..,
      logger: new TypeOrmLoggerContainer(),
      dateStrings: true,
      name: 'cloud_webcast',
      extra: {
        waitForConnections: true,
        connectionLimit: 60, 
        queueLimit: 0
      }
      // timezone: "+HHMM"
    }),
```

I'm using createQueryRunner but it's already released, I'm also using Entity and I noticed that some of the connections were created by Entity, wouldn't Entity be automatically released as per normal?  I don't have any clue now, I need help, thanks!